# How to Make a Lookup connection between two Collection

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Goal:
This sql and its result should be the same result from mongoDB's query code.
 In order words, same result but for mongoDB.

Problem:
How to you make a lookup connection in relation to **People** and **Role** in Mongo DB's query code?

Info:
I'm new in mongo DB

```
SQL code 
    SELECT 
        a.*,
        '.' AS '.',
        b.*,
        '.'  AS '.',
        c.*
    FROM 
        [db1].[dbo].[People_Course_Grade] a
        INNER JOIN [db1].[dbo].[People] b on a.PeopleId = b.PeopleId
        INNER JOIN [db1].[dbo].[Role] c on b.RoleId = c.RoleId
```

[image]

Json data:

```
Role:  
[{"RoleId":1,"Name":"Student"},{"RoleId":2,"Name":"Teacher"}]

People_Course_Grade:   
[{"People_Course_GradeId":1,"PeopleId":1,"CourseId":1}, 
 {"People_Course_GradeId":2,"PeopleId":2,"CourseId":1}, 
 {"People_Course_GradeId":3,"PeopleId":3,"CourseId":2}, 
 {"People_Course_GradeId":4,"PeopleId":1,"CourseId":2}]

Course:
[{"CourseId":1,"Name":"Java"},{"CourseId":2,"Name":"Java II"}, 
 {"CourseId":3,"Name":"Statistik 1"}]
```

[image: Mongo db]

```
db.People_Course_Grade.aggregate([

    {
        $lookup:{
            from: "People",            
            localField: "people_id",   
            foreignField: "_id",       
            as: "people"               
        }
    },
    {   $unwind:"$people" },   


    {   
        $project:{
            course_id : 1,
            people_id : 1,
      //      grade_id : 1,
            Name : "$people.Name",


        } 
    }

]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start with double [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) since you have three collections. Then you can use [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) to always get single element from lookup's result. To flatten your structure you can use [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) with [$mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/index.html) (promotes all the fields from `people` and `course` to root level.

```
db.People_Course_Grade.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup:{
            from: "Role",            
            localField: "PeopleId",   
            foreignField: "RoleId",       
            as: "people"               
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup:{
            from: "Course",            
            localField: "CourseId",   
            foreignField: "CourseId",       
            as: "course"               
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $mergeObjects: [
                    "$$ROOT",
                    { $arrayElemAt: [ "$people", 0 ] },
                    { $arrayElemAt: [ "$course", 0 ] },
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            people: 0,
            course: 0
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zVnFk8q-T-E)

`$arrayElemAt` can always be replaced with `$unwind` like you tried. You also have a naming conflict on `name` field so probably you need to run `$project` to rename one of those fields - otherwise you'll get only one of them in final result.

Comment: I have a question. Is it possibly to use the code above and apply it in view? When you create a view, you have to apply a specific collection.